# Make JButton invisible but respect its original space

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

I am using a `GridBagLayout` and I want to set some buttons as invisible (i.e. they cannot be seen nor clicked), but when I do so using `wdButton.setVisible(false)` the rest of the buttons move. I would like to leave the space originally occupied by the invisibilized button blank and keep the rest unaltered (similar problem to the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495463/how-to-make-a-component-invisible-without-changing-the-location-of-other-elemen)). The solutions proposed there are not useful to me, since I do not want to change the layout.

For the moment, I have been able to do so by using the following lines of code:

```
wdButton.setText("");
wdButton.setOpaque(false);
wdButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
wdButton.setBorderPainted(false);
wdButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Is there a shorter way of achieving this?

Comment: If you just want filler Swing components, why not a JLabel with a space (" ")?

Comment: Because I am trying to hide/show a few buttons in an otherwise static layout. I may want to make the hidden button show up again later.

Comment: *For the moment, I have been able to do so by using the following lines of code:"*  You forgot focus.  But use a `CardLayout`..

Comment: You could just disable the JButton, and enable it when you want it to be active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a shorter way of achieving this?

Create a method and pass in the button as a parameter.

> The solutions proposed there are not useful to me, since I do not want to change the layout.

The solution did not involve changing the layout manager for then entire panel. It involved adding a panel  using a CardLayout containing your button and an empty panel to your main panel.

> I want to set some buttons as invisible

You could replace the button with another component:

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = layout.getConstraints( button );
panel.remove( button );
panel.add( new JLabel(" ");
panel.revalidate();
```

So as you can see whatever you do it will require multiple lines of code, so pick the easiest solution and just move the code to a method so that you only need to use a single statement for each component you want to hide.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am currently using a method created by myself and it's working fine, I was mostly curious about if there was a shorter alternative to those five lines.

Comment: The closing paranthesis for the panel.add is missing. After your edit, I will remove also this comment :)