# Wait a few seconds in Swing

Tags: java, swing, wait

I need to wait a few seconds between invoking two different methods in a program with Swing interface. Those methods are not related to the GUI.

```
firstMethod();
//The interface is changed by other methods
...
//I want to Wait five seconds
secondMethod();
```

I have tried using a `Swing Timer` but it does not work. Apparently, the `Timer` starts but is a non-blocking action, so `secondMethod()` is executed immediately. I can use `sleep()`, but that freezes the GUI for those five seconds, so the interface is not updated until after that, which I would prefer to avoid.

I have found here some recommendations to use `Future<V>` and I have read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) but I have never used `ExecutorService` before and I am afraid I may write a too complex piece of code for something that simple.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: *"Wait a few seconds in Swing [SOLVED]"*  Don't put solutions in questions.  Either write up an answer, or delete it.

Comment: Don't add a "SOLVED" in the title of the question. Instead you should be "accepting" the answer that helped solve the problem. Same for all you other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24337311/131872

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of Java Timer and Thread.sleep.

Please have a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {            
        secondMethod();
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start()
```

Comment: So you have just edited it. Very good. So where is the issue?

Comment: @user2891462 please tell me where is the issue in this approach.

Comment: This approach is perfectly fine, I was using the Timer in a very stupid way. I just edited the original post. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know who **downvoted** the post without leaving any comment.

Comment: Not me, I am planning on selecting it as the valid answer as soon as StackOverflow allows me to.

Comment: Yes I know you are not.

Answer (score 4):

> Sounds like your code is something like:

```
firstMethod();

startTimer();

secondMethod();
```

> I have tried using a Timer but it does not work

You can't just start a Timer and do nothing. When the timer fires you need to invoke the `secondMethod(...)` in the actionPerformed of the Timer.

Answer (score 3):

A timer won't just stop code execution like sleep does.
You have to assign an ActionListener to it which will be notified when the time is up.

It goes something like this:

```
firstMethod();
Timer t = new Timer(5000);
t.setRepeats(false);
t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            secondMethod();    
        }
    })
t.start();
```

Comment: What if secondMethod() is the million lines of code that follows the pause? You don't want the whole program in an actionPerformed().